# problema en el rerendizado condicional de react-native al capturar error de AXIOS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

!Hola amigos¡ Recientemente estoy intendando realizar aplicaciones utilizando react native (yo vengo de VueJs), hasta ahorita no he tenido mayor problema hasta ahorita que estoy intentando implementar un rerendizado condicional para que el elemento no se muestre si no existe.

Tengo esto:

```js
getreportbycode = async() => {
        this.setState({show : false})
        if(this.state.finder !== ''){
            const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('petra-token');
            this.setState({ jwt: token, sendform: true });
            axios.post('https://petrapi.herokuapp.com/emergence/find', {
                report_id : this.state.finder
        }, {headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${this.state.jwt}`
        }
            }).then(response => {
                this.setState({report: response.data.data, sendform:false})
                console.log(this.state.report)
                this.setState({mostrar : true})

        }).catch(error => {
            this.setState({finder:'', sendform:false})
            console.log(error)
        })
        }
    }
```

Y esto (Resumiendolo) :

```js
report(report){
        if(this.state.show == true){
            return(
                <Card>
                    <CardItem>
                            <Left>
                            { report.alert.image == null
                            ?
                            <Thumbnail source={{uri:
                            'https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/user-icon-2-1/100/user_5-15-512.png' }}
                            
                                style={{height: 50, width: 50}}/>
                            :
                            <Thumbnail source={{uri: report.alert.image}}
                            style={{height: 50, width: 50}}/>
                            }
                        </Left>
                        <Body>
                            <Text>
                                Creador: {report.user.name}
                            </Text>
                            {this.proccesbar(report.status)}
                        </Body>
                    </CardItem>
                    </Card>
)} else {
    return(
    <Text>Hello world</Text>
    )
}
```

Lo que estoy intentando implementar es que cuando el usuario ejecute una busqueda le muestre un elemento y si este elemento no existe muestre otra cosa, no obstante la promesa sí se resuelve bien pero cuando intento capturar errores me aparece lo siguiente :

[image: imagen]

Supongo que es por que el objeto al que estoy llamando está vacio pero ¿Existe alguna manera correcta de hacer esto para que ese pedazo de vista no se ejecute si no se cumple una condición ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

podrías cambiar la condición para que primero verifique que venga el valor `alert` dentro de `report`

```
{ !report.alert || report.alert.image == null
    ?
        <Thumbnail source={{uri: 'https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/user-icon-2-1/100/user_5-15-512.png' }} style={{height: 50, width: 50}} />
    :
        <Thumbnail source={{uri: report.alert.image}}} style={{height: 50, width: 50}}/>
}
```